# How to reference JavaScript class via "this" within jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reference, this, javascript-objects

Consider the following JavaScript class, property, and method:

```
function Foo() {
    this.data = 123;
}

Test.prototype.foo = function() {
    $("body").append($("<div>")
        .text("Hello World!")
        .click(function () {
            alert("Data: " + this.data);
        })
    );
}

var Bar = new Foo();
Bar.foo();
```

Why is the property `data` undefined in the alert box? How can "this" be referenced, as pointed to the `Foo` class and not the jQuery `div` element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `this` inside the event handler refers to the element targeted by the handler; you can use a closure variable to hold the object reference like

```
Test.prototype.foo = function () {
    var self = this;
    $("body").append($("<div>")
        .text("Hello World!")
        .click(function () {
        alert("Data: " + self.data);
    }));
}
```

---

Or you can pass a custom execution context to the handler method using methods like [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)/[Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
Test.prototype.foo = function () {
    $("body").append($("<div>")
        .text("Hello World!")
        .click($.proxy(function () {
        alert("Data: " + this.data);
    }, this)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simple. Since you are accessing `this` within the click event callback of jquery element, `this` points to the element on which the event has occurred.

You can change add slight change in the code to make it work, check the jsfiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/satyagupta/efohyekq/

```
Test.prototype.foo = function() {
    var data = this.data;              // <--- Add this line
    $("body").append($("<div>")
        .text("Hello World!")
        .click(function () {
            alert("Data: " + data);
        })
    );
}
```